# firebase auth persistence breaks Expo app. (No firebase app '[DEFAULT]')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

When trying to add persistence to firebase Auth my app breaks. Perhaps anyone here knows what to do? If I remove the persistence part of the initializeAuth everything seems to work OK but obviously it's needed to prevent the user from having to login everytime she starts the app. This happens in the iOS simulator.

my error:

```
 ERROR  FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

My code:

```
import {
    FirebaseApp,
    FirebaseOptions,
    getApp,
    getApps,
    initializeApp,
} from 'firebase/app';

import {
    initializeAuth,
    getReactNativePersistence,
    Auth,
    getAuth,
} from 'firebase/auth/react-native';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
    apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.firebase.apiKey as string,
    authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.firebase.authDomain as string,
    projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.firebase.projectId as string,
    storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.firebase.storageBucket as string,
    messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.firebase
        .messagingSenderId as string,
    appId: Constants.manifest.extra.firebase.appId as string,
    databaseURL: Constants.manifest.extra.firebase.databaseURL as string,
};

const app: FirebaseApp =
    getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

const auth: Auth =
    getApps().length === 0
        ? initializeAuth(app, {
                persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
          })
        : getAuth(app);



export {app, auth};
```